# insert empty page after chapter

Tags: afterpage

I'm sorry, but I'm having trouble inserting a latex code example to explain this problem.

I'm writing a book on environmental hydraulics for university (nothing commercial).

I have a problem inserting a blank page between chapters. I noticed that if the chapter ends with an odd numbered page, the empty page is inserted; if the chapter ends with an even numbered page, the empty page is not inserted.

I thought of two possibilities:

1. force the insertion of an "empty page"
2. use this code: `\afterpage{\null\newpage}`

[image]

with the code I get the insertion of **two pages** (which is quite natural for the book style?) but I would like to insert **only one page** and not two

This is the style of my preamble

```
\documentclass [pdftex, 10pt, a4paper] {book}
\usepackage [a4paper] {geometry}
\setlength {\ oddsidemargin} {0 mm}
\setlength {\ topmargin} {0 mm}
% \setlength {\ headheight} {7 mm}% head height
% \setlength {\ headsep} {9 mm}
\setlength {\ evensidemargin} {0 mm}
\setlength {\ marginparwidth} {0 mm}
\setlength {\ textheight} {230mm}% Text Height
\setlength {\ textwidth 150mm} {}
```

Do you have any suggestions please?

Comment: If you insert only one blank page, the next chapter would begin at page 76, but usually chapters begin on odd-numbered pages.

Comment: if it were an unnumbered page?

Comment: Numbered or unnumbered doesn't make difference ... imagine the book printed ... Chapter should start on the right hand

Comment: Generally speaking, in published books there are either no blank pages between chapters or if chapters always start on a right-hand page then there may be a blank page before it if the previous chapter had ended on a right-hand page. I have never seen a book where there has always been a blank page between chapters.

Comment: the book of notes that I am writing is very didactic. it is designed to be printed on one side only, so I would like a blank page only so that pupils can enter their final notes